# JavaScript href/routing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, codio

I am trying to make a live site but I have run into this issue.

I have a page called 'info' which has been made in the route folder called 'theatre' so that I could href the info page to be opened from the home page. Therefore, the URL includes theatre/info

The code written on the homepage is:

```
**<a class="info" href="theatre/info">
<img src="{{host}}/poster5001.PNG" alt="Thumbnail" width="200"/>
</a>**
```

However, my new problem is that I needed to add a shopping cart to the home & info page. It works perfectly fine from the home page however, when clicked on from the info page the URL becomes theatre/theatre/shopping but I need it to be theatre/shopping. Here is the code that I have used:

```
**<a class="shopping" href="theatre/shopping">
<img src="{{host}}/shopping cart.jpg" alt="Trolley" width="100"/>
</a>**
```

I think the issue is that since the info page is in the theatre route, and I am adding the shopping page to the information page with the same route folder, the route is being doubled. But I don't know how I can fix this.

How can I fix this?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a leading / into the image paths.

Comment: Where in the path should I add this?